# Google Drive raw data?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, raw-data

Is there any URL google has that contains the raw data for the file? using `https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILE_ID` just takes you to a 'share' section of the file... say I have a .js file on GDrive. If you go to their share link, they have a share page. Is there any link to get the raw javascript from the file, as to use in a `<script src="google_link_or_whatever">`?

Comment: Does this help? http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.nl/2012/11/announcing-google-drive-site-publishing.html

Comment: @DaveMorrissey It probably would, thanks, but i'm trying to stay away from APIs. :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Apps Script How to link to JS or CSS file on Google Drive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110264/google-apps-script-how-to-link-to-js-or-css-file-on-google-drive)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NOTE - THIS WAS THE SOLUTION BUT IT NO LONGER WORKS - SEE COMMENT BY @Bobby Fritze below

No API's and no JS necessary.
Confirmed now working on latest version of Drive.
Great workaround for if your server doesn't use https but a vendor plugin demands https to call in a CSS or other file:

1. On the folder with your intended file (e.g. FILE.css), hit Sharing Settings, then Advanced, then select "Public on the web - Anyone on the Internet can find and view."
2. In the URL bar (or share link), copy everything after the drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/
3. Use that ID to replace the XX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX in:  http://googledrive.com/host/XX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX/FILE.css
4. Navigate to the appended URL in Step 3 and you will now see your raw data.

My use case below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var vsDisableResize = false;
var vsCssUrl =         'https://cbe7c864b9c1ae8d5be60c7fed3e467334a04d2f.googledrive.com/host/0B9ngkmVbo5T7TDhTTU81M25iNnc/cart.css';
var vsWineryId = '850';
var vsWineListId = '71';
```

Credit to @chris.huh at: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/MyD7dgLJaEo

Comment: What's this code cbe7c864b9c1ae8d5be60c7fed3e467334a04d2f in your URL?

Comment: Each folder you create in Drive will a string after the /folders/ in the Url; (that's the string noted in Step 3).  The string you're seeing there is output (in a server-side way idk about), because:
http://googledrive.com/host/0BxfRpcEmqYiJRjlJUXozTm80ZlE/why.txt
will point you to a static Url of the raw data

Comment: EDIT: Sometime around late 2016/early 2017, this method of retrieving files from Google Drive stopped working.

Comment: The answer provided here worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26191472/1215260, i.e. set sharing to public as described above and use this URL: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=YOUR_DOCUMENT_ID

Answer (score 32):

First, go to the sharing settings for your document and choose "Anyone with a link." It will generate a link in the format `https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXX/view?usp=sharing`.

Now you can use the following URL format: `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=XXX`

Note that I'm seeing an HTTP redirect when I do this, so use `curl -L` on the command line or otherwise make sure that your HTTP client follows redirect.

Comment: what should I replace xxx with?

Comment: Append `&confirm=t` if the URL points to a binary that Google Drive cannot scan (for example, a `.tar.gz`).

Answer (score 16):

Sharing link:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/YOUR_FILE_ID/view?usp=sharing
```

Raw download link:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=YOUR_FILE_ID
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Someone on a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/libretro/RetroArch/issues/11770) was not able to embed his/her images hosted on Google Drive. With this your syntax it works fine.

Comment: Summing this up in a one-liner for convenience: `wget --content-disposition --trust-server-names $(echo $GDRIVE_NAME | sed -e 's#/file/d/\([^/]\+\)/.*$#/uc?export=download\&id=\1#')`