# Publish a .html file from Google Drive to WordPress

Tags: python, html, wordpress

I'm using Google Colaboratory to create a series of plots using plotly and saving them as .html on Google Drive. I would like to publish does files on a WordPress.

Furthermore, I will update these plots regularly. So every time I update them, they should be updated on WordPress.

Is there a good way to implement this?

Comment: What solutions have you already tried?

Comment: I tried to create a button with the local directory, but it does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there isn't a super easy way to get the HTML doc between Google and WordPress, so the next best thing is to automatically pull the raw document from Drive, and have that integrate on a schedule. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834877/google-drive-raw-data) SO post, get the file id for your document (follow these steps [here](https://pdf.co/how-to-get-direct-download-links)) to be able to access the raw data of your file. **Note: you may want the download link instead, which can be found in the second link.**

`https://drive.google.com/uc?id=file_id`

This may not work, as I've found there's redirection, but you could also possibly use the redirected URL to grab the image. I haven't had much success, however (using curl and wget). After that, you should be able to upload it to WordPress, or have WordPress itself download it and implement it.